# Comparing powers.

Tags: code-golf

Compare two numbers N<sub>1</sub> = a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup>, N<sub>2</sub> = d<sup>e<sup>f</sup></sup> by constructing a function f(a,b,c,d,e,f) that:

- returns 1 if N<sub>1</sub> > N<sub>2</sub>
- returns -1 if N<sub>1</sub> < N<sub>2</sub>

**Note:** You are not required to return any value for any other relation between N<sub>1</sub> and N<sub>2</sub>. e.g. when they are equal or when their relation is undefined (complex numbers).

other constrains:

- all numbers are integers
- a,b,c,d,e,f may be positive or negative but not zero.
- |a|,|d| < 1000
- |b|,|c|,|e|,|f| < 10<sup>10</sup>
- running time less than few seconds

Examples:

```
f(100,100,100,50,100,100) = 1
f(-100,100,100,50,100,100) = 1
f(-100,99,100,50,100,100) = -1
f(100,-100,-100, -1, 3, 100) = 1
f(535, 10^9, 10^8, 443, 10^9, 10^9) = -1
```

This is code golf. Shortest code wins.

Comment: What about if they're equal, should it return 0? Or you assuming that there's no way that N1 will equal N2?

Comment: Can we get some sample input/outputs?

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm not specifying the "being equal" case on purpose. Do as you please. You may even assume that they are never equal.

Comment: @Dogbert: done.

Comment: |b|,|c|,|e|,|f| < 10^10 seems to contradict your last example

Comment: @belisarius: sorry ... fixed it.

Comment: @Eelvex. You should probably say that then. If there's an ambiguous case, then people are going to ask what you meant. And generally, giving requirements for a function which explicitly ignore the result of a valid set of inputs is *not* good. It may be fine for code golf, but even then, I'd suggest that it be explicitly stated that what the function returns in such cases is undefined.

Comment: @Jonathan-M: ok.

Comment: What should we do with, e.g. a=-1,b=2,c=-1?  Taking negative numbers to fractional powers isn't defined.

Comment: @Eelvex : exponentiation is not associative. Do you mean pow(a, pow(b, c)) < pow(d, pow(e, f)), or pow(pow(a, b), c) < pow(pow(d, e), f), or some combination of the two?

Comment: @roobs: The way it is written (a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup>) clearly implies pow(a, pow(b,c)).

Comment: @Keith: Fractional powers of negative integers give clear good old complex numbers. Since you can't directly compare complex numbers, you are not required to do anything. The problems states "return 1 if N1>N2; return -1 if N1<N2" so any other relation between N1, N2 is of no interest here. I'll update the question; thanks :)

Comment: @Eelvex, thanks for clarifying that, if only for me.

Comment: Could we maybe get some more testcases?

Comment: @Ventero: Sure; anything in particular?

Comment: @Eelvex: Not really, I'm just not entirely convinced yet my solution works, so any additional testcase would be great. ;)

Comment: @Eelvex, the specification for cases where the result isn't -1 or 1 is still vague. "You are not required to return any value" - does that mean I can raise an error / throw an exception? Or must I return a value, but I'm not constrained as to what that value is?

Comment: @Peter: *Anything* is ok. You should not expect input that gives anything else than strict, well defined inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Mathematica, 110 chars

```
z[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_]:=With[{g=Sign[a]^(b^c),h=Sign[d]^(e^f)},If[g!=h,g,g*Sign[Log[Abs[a]]b^c-Log[Abs[d]]e^f]]]
```

Comment: What kind of Mathematica do you use there and what magic incantation has to be used to actually get this to work? Putting the above into Mathematica 8 just yields »Syntax::bktwrn: "z(a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_)" represents multiplication; use "z[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_]" to represent a function.« and »Syntax::sntxf: "z(a_" cannot be followed by ",b_,c_,d_,e_,f_):=sgn(ln(abs a)b^c-ln(abs d)e^f)".«

Comment: Fails the testcase `3,-3,3,-4,1,1`, if I'm not completely mistaken (don't have Mathematica here, but Wolfram Alpha [seems to agree](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sgn%28ln%28abs+3%29*%28%28-3%29^3%29-ln%28abs+-4%29*%281^1%29%29)).

Comment: Ok, got it to work now with `z[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_]:=Sign[Log[Abs[a]]b^c-Log[Abs[d]]e^f]` which is considerably longer than what you have there, though. I probably am missing something here.

Comment: @Joey, I don't actually have Mathematica, so I was testing with the Wolfram Alpha interface. It appears that it's much more generous with what it accepts. Ah well - the priority is that @Ventero correctly points out a bug with the logic.

Comment: Will it "run in less than a few seconds" for `z[535, 10^9, 10^8, 443, 10^9, 10^9]`?

Comment: @Eelvex, yes - I timed it at 4 seconds using Wolfram Alpha to evaluate `Sign[535]^((10^9)^(10^8))*Sign[Log[Abs[535]](10^9)^(10^8)-Log[Abs[443]](10^9)^(10^9)]` and it's the expansion of logs to sufficient precision that's the potentially slow bit.

Comment: @Peter: Well, Wolfram Alpha runs on more than 10,000 cpus but OK :)

Comment: @Peter: I wish I could split the bounty but I can't; so, given that wolfram alpha reports errors when I try to evaluate your solution (eg. `(-1)^(10^8)^(10^8)`), I awarded it to Ventero.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby 1.9, <del>280 227 189</del> 171 characters

```
z=->a,b,c,d,e,f{l=->a{Math.log a}
u=->a,b{[a.abs,a][b&1]}
a=u[a,b=u[b,c]]
d=u[d,e=u[e,f]]
d*a<0?a<=>d :b*e<0?b<=>e :(l[l[a*q=a<=>0]/l[d*q]]<=>f*l[e*r=b<=>0]-c*l[b*r])*q*r}
```

I know this is *a bit* longer than the other solutions, but at least this approach should work without calculating a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup>, d<sup>e<sup>f</sup></sup>, b<sup>c</sup> or e<sup>f</sup>.

Edit:

- (279 -> 280) Fixed a bug when `a**b**c < 0` and `d = 1`.
- (280 -> 227) Removed an unnecessary check for a special case.
- (227 -> 192) Removed some checks that aren't necessary with the given criteria (non-zero integers, no output necessary for complex values)
- (192 -> 189) Due to all the other checks, I can safely calculate `log(log(a)/log(d))` instead of `log(log(a))-log(log(d))`.
- (189 -> 171) Simplified way to transform equivalent problems into one another.

Testcases:

```
z[100, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100] == 1
z[-100, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100] == 1
z[-100, 99, 100, 50, 100, 100] == -1
z[100, -100, -100, -1, 3, 100] == 1
z[535, 10**9, 10**8, 443, 10**9, 10**9] == -1
z[-1, -1, 1, 2, 2, 2] == -1
z[1, -5, -9, 2, -1, 2] == -1
z[1, -5, -9, 2, -1, 3] == 1
z[3, -3, 3, -4, 1, 1] == 1
z[-2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] == -1
z[1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1] == 1
z[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1] == -1
z[1, 1, 1, 2, -3, 2] == -1
z[1, 1, 1, 2, -3, 1] == 1
z[-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] == -1
z[2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1] == 1
z[2, -3, 2, 1, 1, 1] == 1
z[2, -3, 1, 1, 1, 1] == -1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ShortScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ShortScript), 89 bytes

```
{CP
$M^ η1 η2
$M^ ζ η3
↑Αζ
$M^ η4 η5
$M^ ζ η6
↔α>ζ↑Ζ1
↔α<ζ↑Ζ-1}
```

The implementation isn't exactly the described one, but it works.

This answer is non-competing, since ShortScript has been published after this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.6 (this doesn't actually work)

```
import cmath
g=cmath.log
f=lambda a,b,c,d,e,f:-1+2*((c*g(b)+g(g(a))-f*g(e)-g(g(d))).real>0)
```

<strike>today i learnt python has a complex log function. so, blindly double log both sides and look at the real component. works for 4 out of the 5 tests. not sure what's happening with the fourth one.</strike>

```
print f(100,100,100,50,100,100) == 1
print f(-100,100,100,50,100,100) == 1
print f(-100,99,100,50,100,100) == -1
print f(100,-100,-100, -1, 3, 100) == 1 # failure, sadness.
print f(535, 10^9, 10^8, 443, 10^9, 10^9) == -1
```

Comment: Well, it is that I messsed up the example that is wrong :/ Sorry ... fixing it...

Comment: my code still returns -1 for the fourth example wrong when a=100

Comment: Comparing just the real part is not correct.

Comment: yeah, that part was a stab in the dark. this is where i regret skipping that course in complex analysis

Answer (score -1):

### Python (99)

```
from math import*
from numpy import*
l=log
def f(a,b,c,d,e,f):return sign(l(a)*l(b)*c-l(d)*l(e)*f)
```

Comment: Fails on negatives.

Answer (score -2):

### Haskell, 44 characters

```
n True=1
n _=1-2
g a b c d e f=n$a^b^c>d^e^f
```

Runs under a second for all the test examples on *my* machine.

Comment: I have a supermachine from the future.

Comment: Also the machine code is highly optimized. Inspecting the compiled code, it does logarithms and other operations. The THC (Trinithis Haskell Compiler) is one smart compiler!!! Who said I had to use GHC or Hugs? In fact, I can provide real source code for my compiler which has a GHC dependency. It will output fast code for this source code even on /your/ machine. What's more, it will compile ANY Haskell program to the same degree of accuracy as the GHC (GHC is the backend).

Comment: @downvoters: I'll provide the whole source code this weekend (I won't be home for a while) for my compiler to prove to you that it runs quickly. Talking about language speed is nonsense, as it all boils down to the compiler/interpreter.

Comment: And I wasn't even talking about bullshit speed/efficiency. I was referring to how (BEFORE you edited the post and changed the function `b` to `n`) the type of function f was given by `f :: (Ord a,
      Num a,
      Integral b2,
      Integral (Bool -> t),
      Integral b,
      Integral b1) =>
     a -> (Bool -> t) -> b -> a -> b1 -> b2 -> t` Pretty strange stuff, huh?